# Symfony: sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable, where is the code that removes the file?

Tags: symfony1

by default, when you replace a file using sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable,
the old file is removed from your hard disk.

Where is that code that removes the file??

Javi

sf 1.3

Answer (score 0):

symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/
sfFormDoctrine.class.php